# Rails 4: Assigning Roles via UI Using Rolify Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using an application based on Devise, CanCanCan and Rolify to handle private resources.

Using Rolify (https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) to assign different roles to users.

I'd like to give access to a web manager who could then assign the multiple roles to users via a UI.

**User Controller:**

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])

params[:user][:role_ids] ||= []

if @user.update_attributes(params[:user_id])
  redirect_to users_path, :flash => { :success => 'User was successfully updated.' }
else
  redirect_to users_path, :flash => { :error => 'User was unsuccesfully updated.' }
end
```

end

**View:**

Accessible via route:

```
get "users/:user_id/edit" => 'user#edit', :as => :edit_user
```

HTML:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% Role.all.each do |role| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include?(role.id) %>
    <%= role.name %><br />
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

**Route:**

```
match "users/:user_id" => 'user#show', via: [:get], :as => :user
```

However, when I click "Update User", I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this up to get my form working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have route to `show` action, accessible via `get`. You should also have a route to `update` action, accessible via `patch`. You can achieve this easily using `resources`:

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :update, :edit]
```

Comment: Marek, I've just updated my question with the route I use to display the form: `get "users/:user_id/edit" => 'user#edit', :as => :edit_user` . Would this still help me?

Comment: @iamryandrake yes, in fact, `resources` also generates `edit` path, like in my answer.

Comment: Is there another way to resolve the patch issue without using resource? My controller is called user_controller, not users_controller so it causes an error.

Comment: @iamryandrake Why don't you rename controller? Of course, you can do it another way, but using `resources` will look much better.